# AWS S3 Lambda WriteFile from stream

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, stream

Using an AWS Lambda, I just want to get an archive (lo.tar.gz) from my s3, copy it to the tmp folder and extract it to the tmp folder.

I have this code in local who work perfectly :

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fs = require('fs');
var targz = require('targz');

var s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('./tmp/lo.tar.gz');
var s3Stream = s3.getObject({ Bucket: 'mybucketname', Key: 'lo.tar.gz' }).createReadStream();

//console.log("Here the last console.log who appear");

// Listen for errors returned by the service
s3Stream.on('error', function (err) {
    // NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist
    console.error(err);
});

s3Stream.pipe(fileStream).on('error', function (err) {
    // capture any errors that occur when writing data to the file
    console.error('File Stream:', err);
}).on('close', function () {
    console.log('Stream Done.');
    // decompress files from tar.gz archive
    targz.decompress({
        src: './tmp/lo.tar.gz',
        dest: './tmp'
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Extract Done!");
        }
    });
});
```

But when I put it in a lambda, nothing append.
It creates an empty file "lo.tar.gz" in tmp and it closes saying "statut:succeeded" and without any error message ... I put "console.log" between each line and the last to appear is the one I left ("Here the last console.log who appear") ...

Does anyone have any idea why the code is not being executed to the end?

Thank you :D!

EDIT : here the exact code for the lambda (the same with exports.handler) :

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var fs = require('fs');
var targz = require('targz');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    var s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
    var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('./tmp/lo.tar.gz');
    var s3Stream = s3.getObject({ Bucket: 'mybucketname', Key: 'lo.tar.gz' 
    }).createReadStream();

    //console.log("Here the last console.log who appear");

    // Listen for errors returned by the service
    s3Stream.on('error', function (err) {
        // NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist
        console.error(err);
    });

    s3Stream.pipe(fileStream).on('error', function (err) {
        // capture any errors that occur when writing data to the file
        console.error('File Stream:', err);
    }).on('close', function () {
        console.log('Stream Done.');
        // decompress files from tar.gz archive
        targz.decompress({
            src: './tmp/lo.tar.gz',
            dest: './tmp'
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Extract Done!");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is the file smaller than 512mb?

Comment: Yes the file is 134mb

Comment: The code you've shown is not a Lambda function. Please include the actual Lambda function code. Also, what does CloudWatch Logs for this Lambda function tell you? Did it time out, or complete successfully?

Comment: @jarmod I just added the exact lambda code. He tells me that it's complete successfully ! Like if the code after the console.log("last who appear") doesn't exist ...